# CLGeocoder reverse geocode from given location

Tags: ios, maps, clgeocoder

Given a longitude and latitude **not my current location** how can I perform a reverse geocode lookup using `GLGeocoder`?

```
self.geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
//    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

[self.geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation: locationManager.location completionHandler: ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
//        [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

     CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
    // Long address
    // NSString *locatedAt = [[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
    // Short address
    NSString *locatedAt = [placemark subLocality];

     cell.textLabel.text = spot.name;
     cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cab no: %@, spotted at %@", spot.cabno, locatedAt];
 }];
```

Will obviously only ever geocode my location,  but I need to explicitly set the longitude and latitude to reverse from.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I never tried this, but can't you create your own CLLocation object?

If you know current longitude and latitude you can -

```
CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:someValue longitude:someValue];
[self.geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation: location completionHandler: ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    //do something
});
```

Comment: Smashed! Thank you. I did try to `initWithLatitude` but it must've been on `CLLocationManager` rather than a `CLLocation` object. Cheers!

Comment: Great, you have saved me.

Comment: I also used this to reverse geocode from a PFGeoPoint works amazing!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the simulator, you can debug>location>Custom Location then put in lat long to simulate a location anywhere.